# Inferior Limit of a Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

Given two events A and B such that $P(A) = P(B) = \frac{4}{5}$. What is the inferior limit of $P(A|B)$?

I'm having troubles figuring it out to some other examples so if someone could do this one and explain it, it would help me a lot

Comment: What have you tried?  How far can you get?

Comment: Not much, I thought about thinking that their maximum value would occur if they were independent, so the superior limit would be 4/5

Comment: But I got nothing about the inferior one

Comment: Didn't you try writing down the formula for $\Pr(A|B)$?

Comment: You mean P(A|B) = P(AB) / P(B) (consider AB the intersection of A and B)?

Comment: Exactly.  What do you conclude from that?

Comment: I'm not sure, can you go a little further?

Comment: @Learner If the events are small enough that they might be disjoint, then their intersection's probability could be at least zero, otherwise if the sum of the events probabilities exceeds $1$, then their intersection's probability cannot be smaller than this excess.  Which is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\Pr(A|B)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}= \frac54\Pr(A\cap B)$$ so that $\Pr(A|B)$ is smallest when $\Pr(A\cap B)$ is smallest.

Now $\Pr(A\cap B)\geq\frac35$ (why?), so $\Pr(A|B)\geq\frac34$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I now understood it

Comment: @Learner My pleasure.